Why isn't this object being created? It didn't show up
I'm quite new to GML Code so sorry. But I have a problem at here:
So, I wanted so that this Object (Obj_gold) when you hold a key, it would make an aimer (Obj_aimer) and then when you stop holding that key, the aimer gets destroyed. Here's how I do it:
The key when hold:
move = true;
instance_create_layer(mouse_x,mouse_y,"Instances",Obj_aimer)

The key when it was stopped held:
instance_create_layer(x,y,"Instances",Obj_bullet)
instance_destroy(Obj_aimer);

Here's what I coded for the aimer when created:
while Obj_gold.move = true
{
    x = mouse_x
    y = mouse_y
}

Can please someone help me?
I tried to do the code mentioned, however when holding the key it creates nothing.

Instance_create_layer is the correct way to create an object, and the variables are assigned properly.
Have you made sure there's an "Instances" layer within the room itself?  Else it can't find the layer to place the object. (I think It's also Case-sensitive)
Another case is that the object is created correctly, but it doesn't show up. This could be, for example, out-of-bounds, the object or the layer's visibility is false or the layer is behind a background layer.
